# Briançon ne serait plus qu'un souvenir flou

Tags: conditionnel

*Paris-Briançon* de Philippe Besson :

> C'est du reste l'infatigable ambition de ce dernier (*) qui les avait
> conduits à quitter Briançon. Ayant décroché un très bon job à La
> Défense, et le salaire qui allait avec, il avait annoncé que c'était
> terminé, les Alpes, les sommets enneigés, la maison de pierre . Et la
> famille s'était retrouvée à Neuilly. Le garçon n'avait que sept ans.
> Pendant longtemps, le soir venu, en cherchant le sommeil, il allait
> avoir le regret des sommets enneigés, de la maison de pierre et, un
> jour, ça lui **était passé**. Briançon ne **serait** plus qu'un
> souvenir flou. C'est pourtant là qu'il **revient** aujourd'hui.

(*) le père du garçon

*Était passé* est au passé, *revient* est au présent. Briançon est un souvenir flou au moment où l'auteur écrit ces lignes, c'est un fait. Pourquoi alors il emploie le conditionnel *serait* ?

Answer (score 2):

Le conditionnel exprime le futur vu du passé dans ce texte.

> ([Lettres au collège](http://lettres.clg.free.fr/?Valeurs-du-conditionnel)) Les valeurs temporelles du conditionnel
>
> - Il exprime le futur (vu) du passé, en présentant une action envisagée dans l’avenir depuis un moment du passé.
>   ♦ Il était évident à ce moment-là que Paul arriverait à l’heure. Au moment du passé envisagé ("à ce moment-là") l’arrivée de Paul ne s’est pas encore produite : c’est une action future, vue du passé.